# Prevent android app crash when callable firebase function throws exception

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-functions

My Firebase callable function needs to notify the client when invalid values are passed. [According to documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) this should be done using `functions.https.HttpsError`-

```
      if (!condition) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
          'invalid-argument',
          'Cheating will incur ban'
        );
      }
```

Adding the client side code to call the function as [given in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors_on_the_client) causes the app to crash.

```kotlin
    fun addPlayTime(playTime: Int): Task<String> {
        val data = hashMapOf(
            "playTime" to playTime
        )
        return functions
            .getHttpsCallable("addPlayTime")
            .call(data)
            .continueWith { task ->
                val result = task.result?.data as String
                result
            }
    }
```

```kotlin
            viewModel.addPlayTime(10000)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    Timber.d("API response: ${task.result}")
                    if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                        val e = task.exception
                        if (e is FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                            val code = e.code
                            val details = e.details
                            Timber.d("API call failed: $details")
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I'm able to see the error in logcat. How do I handle this exception without my app crashing? Wrapping the above code in try-catch didn't help.

```sh
2020-07-31 19:04:28.722 17502-17502/com.teamvanar.gcharge E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.teamvanar.gcharge, PID: 17502
    com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: Cheating will incur ban
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source:15)
        at com.teamvanar.gcharge.MainActivity$onCreate$2.onComplete(MainActivity.kt:67)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: Cheating will incur ban
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Firebase Http Callable has some type-transform (reflection?) issues when it uses `CompleteListener` in Kotlin, and those FATALs cannot be caught by try-catch.

Replace it with `SuccessListener` and `FailureListener` solve that in my case:

```
// from this
someFirebaseFunction.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        task.result?.let { /* do something */ }
    } else {
        println("Error: ${task.exception}")
    }
}

// to this
someFirebaseFunction.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
    /* do something */
}.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        println("Error: $exception")
    }
}
```

In your case, this might work:

```
viewModel.addPlayTime(10000).addOnSuccessListener { result ->
    Timber.d("API response: $result")
}.addOnFailureListener { e ->
    if (e is FirebaseFunctionsException) {
        val code = e.code
        val details = e.details
        Timber.d("API call failed: $details")
    }
}
```